# How to show web site column in custom module custom grid in admin magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid

https://prnt.sc/AVRLsd7GLrKz

> Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Tool\Edit\Tab\View;

```
$this->addColumn(
        'website_id',
        [
            'header' => __('Web Site'),
            'index' => 'website_id',
            //'filter' => false,
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => ['1'=>'Website One','2'=>'Website Two'],
            'renderer'  => 'Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Tool\Renderer\Website',
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Tool\Renderer\Website

```
<?php

 namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Tool\Renderer;

 use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
 use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Website extends AbstractRenderer
{
   protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
  
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Magento\Store\Api\WebsiteRepositoryInterface $websiteRepository
)
{
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->_websiteRepository = $websiteRepository;
}

public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
{
    $customerId = $row->getData('entity_id');
    
    $customerData = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    
    $websiteId = $customerData->getWebsiteId();
    
    $website = $this->_websiteRepository->getById($websiteId);
    return $website->getName();
 }
```

}